# why is $this->field not always returning a value inside laravel custom attribute model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a custom attribute inside my model.

if I try to get the value of i.e **`$this->id`** it works but if I add a new column to that model and call it **`$this->new_column`** it returns empty even though it has a value. So in order to retrieve it, I have to then initialise the model again inside the custom attribute.

```
$model = MyModel::find($this->id);
```

just so I can access **`$model->new_column`**

```
public function getCustomColumnDataAttribute(){
    Log::info($this->id); //returns the value
    Log::info($this->new_column); //doesn't return the value

    $model = MyModel::find($this->id);
    Log::info($model->new_column); //returns the value
}
```

I find it a waste to always initialise the model again just so I can access the values. Or am I missing something here with how `$this` works inside the model function?

Comment: i have tried it   $user=\App\Models\User::find(1)->custom_column; and in model   public function getCustomColumnAttribute(){

        return $this->testing;
    }  and it works fine

Comment: also make sure ,you have created new_column in database table otherwise it return null

Comment: @JohnLobo the columns are all present in the database. I do think this is a server thing since it happens on one server but doesn't on another so not really sure why that would affect how laravel eloquent works.